# php connection microsoft access with password

Tags: php, mysql

I have to connect to an old Microsoft Access database that has only the database password that is used on a desktop program, so I have no variation with to convert it to mysql, this is my attempt to connect:

```
<?php
    $dbName = "dati.mdb";
    $user = "";
    $password = "gmpa";
    $connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbName"$user,$password);
?>
```

Comment: i assume your problem is a syntax error caused by the missing `,` between the first 2 arguments of the `odbc_connect` function `Dbq=$dbName"$user`. otherwise what is your problem

Comment: How that's possible like without username microsoft access have password ? I think there is must be any user which can access ma with this password

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax for odbc:

```
$db = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=dati.mdb", '', 'gmpa');
```

If it fails, try with the default username "Admin":

```
$db = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=dati.mdb", 'Admin', 'gmpa');
```

If it still fails, you probably need to specify the full path to the database file, for example:

```
$db = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=C:\\Users\\You\\Desktop\\dati.mdb;", 'Admin', 'gmpa');
```